# How to authenticate in MySQL RDS using IAM DB Authentication and Python

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I have an AWS RDS DB running MySQL 5.6.39, with IAM DB Authentication Enabled.

First of all, I completed with success the [Tutorial: Configuring a Lambda Function to Access Amazon RDS in an Amazon VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/vpc-rds.html) and this was my starting point for the next steps.

I want to log in with IAM credentials  and so, following [this](https://medium.com/@franciscoed/connecting-to-rds-using-iam-user-86de4401086e) and [this](https://cloudonaut.io/passwordless-database-authentication-for-aws-lambda/) tutorials, I did:

1. When I created the RDS MySQL instance, I selected `Enabling IAM database authentication`.
2. Created a user named `lambda`:

   ```
   CREATE USER 'lambda' IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin as 'RDS';
   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test_db.* TO 'lambda'@'%';
   FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
   ```
3. Created an IAM policy, and attached it to the role I was using  as an Execution role for my lambda function:

   ```
   {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
       {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Action": [
           "rds-db:connect"
         ],
         "Resource": [
           "<DB-ARN>/lambda"
         ]
       }
     ]
   }
   ```
4. Created a lambda function:

   ```
   import sys
   import boto3
   import logging
   import pymysql

   #rds settings
   rds_host  = "<RDS-ENDPOINT>"
   username = "lambda"
   db_name = "test_db"

   logger = logging.getLogger()
   logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

   client = boto3.client('rds',region_name='eu-west-2')
   token = client.generate_db_auth_token(rds_host,3306, name)
   ssl = {'ca': 'rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem'} 
   logger.info("token: "+ token)

   conn = pymysql.connect(rds_host, user=username, passwd=token, db=db_name, connect_timeout=5, ssl=ssl)

   logger.info("SUCCESS: Connection to RDS mysql instance succeeded")
   def handler(event, context):
     ...
   ```
5. I got the following error:

   ```
   error: (1045, "Access denied for user 'lambda'@'<LAMBDA_IP>' (using password: YES)")
   ```

In an attempt to find If it was a python error I used AWS CLI, from an EC2 instance with the policy attached.

1. Get the token:

   ```
   aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname <RDS-ENDPOINT> --port 3306 --username lambda
   ```
2. Connect to the DB, using the token I got in the last step:

   ```
   mysql -h <RDS-ENDPOINT> -u lambda --enable-cleartext-plugin --password='<TOKEN>'
   ```
3. I got the same error:

   ```
   mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
   ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'lambda'@'<EC2_IP>' (using password: YES)
   ```

Comment: Note that no authentication happens when you *generate* the token.  The tokens are exactly like a pre-signed URL -  they are generated locally, without any interaction with any API, and not actually checked until you try to use them.

Comment: Do you mean that probably the problem is in how I'm getting the token? My most significant doubt was in the policy because AWS Management Console gave me this info ``IAM does not recognize this service. The service might include a typo or might be a previewed or custom service.``

Comment: In the policy, the resource portion of your ARN (after the account number and the following `:`) needs to include the literal string `dbuser:` + the db identifier (which begins with `db-`) + `/` + the username.  The IAM console doesn't understand these policies, so that warning is normal.

Comment: Also, no, I didn't intend to suggest that there is a problem with the way you are getting the token, but rather checking to be sure that you understand that being able to get a token does not prove anything one way or another about your configuration.  Any user can get a token, even with invalid or fictitious credentials.  It won't work for logging in, but it will still be generated.

Comment: Changed the ``Resource`` according to what you said. It failed again but I will wait some time to make sure the changes have propagated

Comment: Working! Thank you very much. I spend more than three hours on this... It was a stupid mistake, but it may happen to others and finding the (rest of the) steps to do this wasn't easy. Do you want to write an answer or do you prefer I do so?

Comment: Thank you for offering, but please feel free to go ahead and post an answer explaining what you found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The policy is not correct!

The `Resource` is not the DB ARN, but `"arn:aws:rds-db:<AWS_REGION>:<AWS_ACCOUNT_ID>:dbuser:<AWS_DB_RESOURCE_ID>/<DB_USERNAME>"`

To get this information from the management console, you can go to:

- **AWS_REGION** - The region code, for example `eu-west-2` or any other from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html).
- **AWS_ACCOUNT_ID** - Get it from the [Account Settings](https://console.aws.amazon.com/billing/home?#/account).
- **AWS_DB_RESOURCE_ID** - Find it in `Details\Configuration\Resource ID` in the DB page and it starts with `db-`.
- **DB_USERNAME** - Is `lambda` because it was the one created in step 2.

By the way, and as [Michael - sqlbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1695906/michael-sqlbot) pointed out here and in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45204809/4470542), the generation of the token is local so getting it should not be interpreted as getting a correct password.

Comment: NBajanca, @Michael - sqlbot - I am getting the same exact error and not able to figure out what is going wrong. Already spent almost half a day on this and still haven't reached anywhere. My IAM Policy is exactly same as you mentioned. With you Step 2 in AWS CLI above, are you asked to enter a password? If yes, what password did you enter for 'lambda'? I am getting asked a password not matter what I enter I get the error. How come you are not specifying "--ssl-ca=<PEM file>" in your `mysql` command? I posted a question on this just few minutes ago: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50383753/5277048.