# AWS RDS MySQL connection using IAM Role is not working

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-iam

Would like to inform upfront that I am new to AWS in general. For my project I am trying to use AWS RDS MySQL using IAM Authentication (IAM Role) from a Java application deployed on Tomcat on an EC2 instance. Before trying it from Java I am trying it from the command prompt on the EC2 instance. I am following this link to do it:

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/

I have done the following so far (please pardon if I am not using correct terminologies):

- MySQL using AWS RDS
- Enabled IAM Authentication on my MySQL instance
- Created IAM Role for EC2
- Created an inline policy for the above IAM Role and granted required "Action". Also included the "Resources" (my database's endpoint with username), as below:

  ```
  {
     "Version": "2012-10-17",
     "Statement": [
         {
             "Effect": "Allow",
             "Action": [
                 "rds-db:connect"
             ],
             "Resource": [
                 "arn:aws:rds-db:<my-region>:<my-account-id>:dbuser:<my-db-resource-id>/<my-db-username>"
             ]
         }
     ]
  }
  ```
- Assigned this IAM Role to an EC2 instance I have created

I followed everything given in the [link at the top](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/users-connect-rds-iam/) and everything seem to work except for the last command.

As in the link I created **DB user** as below:

`CREATE USER dev_user IDENTIFIED WITH AWSAuthenticationPlugin as 'RDS';`

The last command in the link that is not working is:

`mysql -h {db or cluser endpoint} --ssl-ca={certificate file name with complete path} --ssl-verify-server-cert -u {dbusername2} -p"{authenticationtoken}" --enable-cleartext-plugin`

Every time I run this command it asks for the password and then I am getting an error. I am at a loss on how to resolve it.

In the above mysql command if I pass my **master user-id** (I created it as 'admin') and enter it's password I get an error like this:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-16 ~]$ mysql -h <endpoint of my RDS DB instance> --ssl-ca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert -u admin -p 'aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname <endpoint of my RDS DB instance> --port 3306 --username dev_user' --enable-cleartext-plugin
```

**Enter password: 
ERROR 1059 (42000): Identifier name 'aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname  --port' is too long**

And if in the same command I provide the above created DB user (dev_user). I get the following error if provide "dev_user" as user in the command and whether I enter a password or not. **[In this case, the above link did not set a password so what should I do when it asks to enter the password?]**:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xx-xx-16 ~]$ mysql -h <endpoint of my RDS DB instance> --ssl-ca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert -u dev_user -p 'aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname <endpoint of my RDS DB instance> --port 3306 --username dev_user' --enable-cleartext-plugin
```

**Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'dev_user'@'xxx.xx.xx.16' (using password: YES)**

I get the same "Access denied..." error when I enter "admin" in both places in the command above.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I've never used IAM, but is there any reason why you can't just configure your security groups to allow the EC2 and MySQL instances to communicate with each other (this is the setup I use, and it works fine).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen this is not a security group issue because error 1045 indicates that connectivity is present, but access is denied.  IAM auth is slightly tedious to figure out when getting started, but *extremely* useful, because you no longer need to embed passwords in your code or otherwise manage them.  IAM auth uses something which, under the hood, is very similar to a pre-signed URL as a password.

Comment: @Gauzy this should not ask you for a password.  Ensure that there is no space in `-p<here>'token'` or use `--password='token'`.  If you are getting prompted for a password, that is a problem with the format of your command line.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Good to know.

Comment: The other annoyance is that the IAM policy editor doesn't understand how these ARNs or policies work, or what `rds-db:connect` is, so it can't help you get it right... and the db-resource-id is a string like `db-XXXXXX` that is visible in the console but that many users are unlikely to have ever given much attention.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot - thanks for the reply, highly appreciated! Lost lot of time. How do you know about no space in '-p' and 'token'? You and @SergeyKovalev helped me resolve this. And both are providing the correct and required information. You confirmed that it should not ask for password and @SergeyKovalev cleared that those are actually ticks (`) and not single quotes ('). I am not able to mark your reply as answer since it's a comment. I will go ahead and mark @SergeyKovalev's as answer but so that other people get complete info, I will also add a comment to refer to your reply here. Thanks!

Comment: Michael-sqlbot and SergeyKovalev - I have one more doubt, would be great if you can shed some light. AWS documentation says there are limitations in accessing RDS with IAM Authentication as in the link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html. If this is the case then why should we go this route? I have posted it as a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50393670/5277048

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there shouldn't be space after `-p` parameter.

Second, if you want to execute `aws rds generate-db-auth-token...` inline, it should be marked with ticks, not single quotes.

```
mysql -h <endpoint of my RDS DB instance> --ssl-ca=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem --ssl-verify-server-cert -u dev_user -p`aws rds generate-db-auth-token --hostname <endpoint of my RDS DB instance> --port 3306 --username dev_user` --enable-cleartext-plugin
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those mistakes and for resolving, much appreciated! Why does the space works with some parameters but not others. What's the standard? I should have paid attention to ticks instead of single quotes, came across it in one of the SO replies and just used it. Your reply and Michael-sqlbot helped me clear my understanding. If I could I would mark both your and his replies as answers. To those who come here afterword: please refer to @Michael-sqlbot's comment above also he also confirms that if the command is correct it won't ask for password. Thanks!